# DataTables gem won't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, datatables

I can't get the jquery-datatables-rails gem to work. I suspect bootstrap 3 from the bootstrap-sass gem is causing the issue.

gems

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
```

table

```
<table id="table" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= item.id %></td>
     <td><%= item.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-ui
```

application.css.scss

```
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#table').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
```

I some datatables styling to works. but none of the js features work, its basically just a blank table. I've gone over the installs a few times over and googled everything i can but cant find what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by doing the following:

- Removing the Datatables gem and reinstalling it, and ensuring that I installed with the boostrap3 argument.
- Creating the table from scratch.
- Assigining a css class (instead of an id)  and using the class in my js file to reference the table (e.g. in my view: table class="newtable" and in my js $(.newtable))
- Ensuring that the table tags were balanced (as in, making sure there are same number of th tags as td tags).
- Removing the div (that Rails generates by default) in the index view (around the table).

I hope that helps, if you require additional detail then let me know.